# How do I log-in to a user in my /home/ folder after mounting/copying it?

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions

I recently had to clean-install my Ubuntu system. So I created a separate partition, and installed Ubuntu there. Afterwards, in my newly installed Ubuntu, I mounted my old partition and copied all my files into my new home folder. I am currently logged in the new user I created. How do I log in to the users I copied into the home folder?

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Nov 16 14:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Nov 13 14:14 ..
drwxrwxrwx 33 root root 4096 Nov 13 10:41 apps
drwxr-xr-x 42 moji moji 4096 Nov 12 14:10 jasmine
drwxr-xr-x 22 moji moji 4096 Nov 16 14:36 moji
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Nov  4 10:08 moji2
drwxr-xr-x 14 temp temp 4096 Nov 16 14:41 temp
```

jasmine, moji2 are the folders I want to log in. moji was created during the clean install, and temp was creating in moji (moji and temp can both be deleted)

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and run the command `ls -la /home`. [Edit] your question and add the output of the command.

Comment: updated the output

Comment: @user66253 gave you the perfect answer.

Comment: to confirm it would be sudo adduser --home /home/jasmine jasmine ?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is answered in [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1308767) thread.

I.e. you need to recreate the users by nominating the home folder and in case fix the permissions after.

```
sudo adduser --home /home/your_sister your_sister
sudo chown -R your_sister:your_sister /home/your_sister
```

Comment: I am stuck in a login loop when trying to access the old user (jasmine). Is it because when asked to create a password for jasmine, I used a new one? (a different one from jasmine?)

Comment: Did yo use the home folder encryption? What happens, if you are logging in from a virtual terminal (e.g. CTRL+ALT+F2)? Are you seeing some error messages which could be useful?